# How can I translate this hexadecimal code?

Tags: cipher

I've recently gotten into cryptography and found a code which I just have not been able to decrypt. Any help? All I know is its in hexadecimal notation due to the 0x notation. Here it is: `0xB105F00D 0x6FA830D3`

I think there's a time limit I have on how long to work out, but I'm not sure. I have tried using an alphanumeric cipher, Caesar shift etc. to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its not hexadecimal as that isn't a valid input

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil it *is* valid hexadecimal; `B105F00D FA830D3` contains only 0-9 and A-F. There might be a digit missing from the second term, though.

Comment: Yes, it is valid hexadecimal. Doesn’t mean you should try to interpret it as hexadecimal, though :-)

Comment: `0xB105F00D` is (coincidentally perhaps) Hexspeak for **"BIOS FOOD"**, I'm not sure about the second bit though. Try mixing out the numbers for letters they look like or sounds they're similar to (ST8, for example, could be State or S33 could be See).

Comment: Bit of a stretch, but 0xFA830D3 could be FAB CODE (8 is B, 3 is C??, 0 is O, 3 is E).

Comment: Oh god xD i just saw its 6FA830D3

Comment: If there is a time limit, this would be an ongoing competition? We can not help with those..

Comment: Well im not sure, but im rather new to codebreaking so i really just would like some tips really on how to go about cracking code :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try xor.pw and copy 0xB105F00D into the first box and 0x6FA830D3 in the second box then press 'calculate XOR' and what appears in the 3rd box is your code
You`ll get:

> deadc0de

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Have you tried the 'calculate xor' yourself? It'd be best to do that and edit that into your answer; otherwise, leave this as a comment.

Comment: yes i have tried this and i can confirm that it does work

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a digit at the end of the second hex code.
**0xB105F00D 0x0BAF5AA0**
Using the website Glorfindel suggested, I managed to solve the puzzle.
Remove the "0x" from both hex codes and input the remainder of the hex code into the first and second box on xor.pw.

That'll give you the solution you seek.

> baaaaaad

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! Please can you [edit] the details of the solution into your post? (You can use `>!` at the start of a paragraph to hide text behind a spoilerblock in case the OP wants to figure out parts of it on their own.) Really answers posted here should be complete rather than just pointers.

Comment: Sure no problem!